# Visual Studio 2010: Pre-order purchase available? With using 2008 in mean time?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, release, purchase-order

Does anyone know if you can pre-order purchase Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and get the current edition (2008) for use in the meantime, until 2010 launches in March?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy VS2008 Professional with an MSDN subscription, you will automatically get upgraded to VS2010 Premium Edition when it gets released ([source](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/howtobuy/ultimate-offer.mspx)).

If you don't want to buy an MSDN subscription along with VS (or you only really want VS2010 Professional), I suggest you use the Beta 2 version of VS2010 (which comes with a GoLive licence enabling you to release and deploy what you make with it) until it is released and then purchase it when it is released in April. You can get VS2010 Beta 2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx).

Comment: +1, accepted and thanks: succinctly covers all the options available to me. If only Microsoft could communicate in this way!

Comment: Just some observations for anyone else considering similar endeavours: Install of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 is very long in duration time - it's not a 10 minute job for sure, more like an hour at least I think. Given that fact, unfortunately it's not something you can go off and leave unattended overnight say because as part of the install it's stopped with a dialog asking to restart my machine twice. Windows XP Pro SP3 on Intel Pentium D 3.00 GHz 1.0Gb RAM.

Comment: Replace "Beta2" with "RC" unless you need it today (as RC will be publicly downloadable tomorrow, today it is MSDN subs only).